# Measuring the significance of label co-occurrences in a multi-label setup

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset where each instance (sentence) is labelled with one or two labels of a given labelset of 4 possible labels. Some sentences have only one label, some have two:

| Instance | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Sentence1 | A |
| Sentence2 | B |
| Sentence3 | A, B |
| Sentence4 | C |
| Sentence5 | A, D |
| ... | ... |

I have a table with the overall frequencies of labels,

| Label | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| A | 85 |
| B | 12 |
| C | 2200 |
| D | 3300 |

and a table of all labels occurring together (that means, they are assigned to the same sentence, the order of the labels is not important):

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 |  |  |  |
| C | 5 | 2 |  |  |
| D | 4 | 7 | 109 |  |

Obviously, C and D often are assigned to the same sentence, but since both are very frequent labels in the dataset, this might not mean a lot.

Now my question is: What would be a good way of calculating co-occurrences of the labels, taking into account the frequency of the labels in the corpus?

Thanks a lot in advance!